# Getting variable into JS via PHP assigned id

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following Javascript to generate a silent call to another sheet to update a database value without refreshing the page

```
function UpdateDB(table,column,type){
    var value = $("#Assigned").val();

    $.post("UpdateValuation.php?Table=" + table + "&Value=" + value + "&Column=" + column + "&Type=" + type, {}).done();
};
```

This works perfectly but only for the "Assigned" table row since it is statically assigned.

I use the following php to generate the table entry with button

```
print "<tr><td>" . $stuff['Status'] . "</td><td ><input type=\"text\" id=\"" . $stuff['Status'] . "\" name=\"" . $stuff['Status'] . "\" value=". $stuff['Value'] ." size = \"4\" style = \"text-align: center\"/><button onclick=\"UpdateDB('NOCstatus','Status','". $stuff['Status'] ."');\">Update</button></td></tr>";
```

Which after variables are assigned looks like this for my "Pending" row

```
<input id="Pending" type="text" style="text-align: center" size="4" value="120" name="Pending">    </input>
<button onclick="UpdateDB('NOCstatus','Status','Pending');">
Update
</button>
```

My problem is that passing "this.value" or trying to use a variable in the javascript portion I always come up with a blank value, the only time I can get a value to be correct is by statically assigning the "#Assigned" or "#Pending" in the value field. I have hundreds of entries so I don't want to write the function over for each of these. I know there is probably something extremely simple I am missing but I cannot get the pieces to fit.

I need to pass the typed in value in the input field to the function to update the database. Please help.

Comment: Not sure if i understand but this.value will not get set in your code because the id is "Pending" when your php is generating it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function UpdateDB(table,column,type){
    var value = $('#'+type).val();

    $.post("UpdateValuation.php?Table=" + table + "&Value=" + value + "&Column=" + column + "&Type=" + type, {}).done();
};
```

?

Comment: Yes, this is it. I had tried it previously but with double quotes and it did not work. I knew it was something simple. Thank you, I will accept answer in a few minutes when it is available.